# Nsurlsession memory leak when downloading image with from URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory, memory-leaks

I have a very simple iOS app that pulls images from firebase, adds them to an array, then puts them in a collection view with a url session. Only one problem, the view that holds the collection view of images is a separate view from the main view, so each time the user clicks to the view, I watch the memory usage sore. The when you click back, the memory does not change. Each time the view is pushed, the memory usage keeps rising. I have never experienced this problem before when I did the url session in the main view, but now I have issues in the separate view. Here is my code for downloading the image:

for grabbing image:

```
      let ref = firdatabase.dadatabase.reference
 ref.child("Pages").queryOrderedByKey.observeSingleEvent(type: .value,    snapshot in 

if let pages = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
for (_, vale) in pages {
let newPage = page()
If let url = vale["url"] as? String {
 newpage.url = url
 pagers.append(new page)
 }
 }
collection view.reloadData()

 )}
```

nsurlsession:

```
  if pagers.count != 0 {
    let post = pagers[indexPath.row].url
        let url = URL(string: post!)
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let errer = error {
                print(errer.localizedDescription)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageViewPage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        })session.resume()



    }
    return cell
```

Now here is the problem though, the memory keeps rising and not ever dropping.

[image]

I really need your help to find a solution to this problem because I have no idea how, and have never had this problem before.Thank you. I am hoping there is a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: Run the Leaks instrument to look for leaked instances.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear that you **have** a memory leak. Just because memory use goes up does not mean you have a memory leak.

If you load images from a remote URL and save them in an array then your memory use will go up.

If you leave the view controller and discard the array and your memory use goes back down, you don't have a memory leak.

Note that your code is installing your images into table view/collection view cells but not saving them anywhere. That means that if the user scrolls a cell off-screen, then scrolls back to it, you'll download it again.

Instead, I would suggest writing your code to save your images to disk as files. You can create a hash of the file URL and use that as the filename. Check to see if the file is already on disk, (probably in your app's caches directory) and load it from from disk if so. If not, use an URLSession download object and save the file to your hash filename in the caches directory when the download is complete, and then install it in the target cell.

Comment: ok well I never clear the array once i dismiss the view controller, I am wondering why it doesn't clear the memory when I dismiss the view

Comment: Who owns the array? You need to edit your question to show the code that manages the array of images, as well as explain the lifecycle of the view controller that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invalidate your session task once it completes to avoid memory leak

```
urlSession.invalidateAndCancel()
```

Comment: I tried doing UrlSession.invalidateAndCancel(session) after the session, and this gives me an error

Comment: Instance member 'invalidateAndCancel' cannot be used on type 'URLSession'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: I think you need to define the instance variable like this var session: URLSession in your class and use the same across the class.

Comment: I was not able to do it that way, because it then changes the setup of my code: http://imgur.com/a/ARTSm